# Getting second td element with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to get several elements from a web-page. To accomplish this, I decided to use Jsoup. The image below shows parts of the html portions I would like to extract:

[image]

I need get the elements marked with red. The first name i can get with:

```
String url = "";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements links = doc.select("td.DifFlSb");
for(Element x:links){
   System.out.println(x.getElementsByTag("a").first().text());
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to extract the data in the second `td`. I tried with regular expressions but nothing. The `td` has not a class or id so i don't know how to make it.

Comment: You might want to look into xpath

Comment: Edit your title to be specific to your problem/issue.

Comment: It's much better to include the HTML as code rather than an image. Makes it easier for someone to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `Elements secondTds = doc.select("tr td+td");`

This will target the second `td`. This works because `select` method accepts a `cssQuery` format.

**example:**

```css
tr td+td {color: red;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Content td 1</td>
<td>Content td 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Content td 1</td>
<td>Content td 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This will however get every ```td``` that has a sibling ```td``` element before itself. In the OP this would lead to more hits, since there are more than two ```td``` elements per ```tr```

Comment: If you look at the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCFSc.jpg) of the portions that need to be extracted, you will see that it makes sense to collect all second `td`s

Comment: sorry, did not mean to be rude at all, just wanted to demonstrate the flaw by using a sole css selector answer. Will remove my your/my demo from my answer now. Just add some more tds to your answer and it should become clear what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this one very easily with Jsoup and some Java.

```
Elements trs = doc.select("tr");
for (Element tr : trs){
  Elements tds = tr.select("td");
  if (tds && tds.size() > 0){
    Element secondTd = tds.get(1);
    //do whatever you need to do with td 
  }
}
```

Note that my code above is untested. I do not have a Java environment with me, so this is just typed in the answer box of Stackoverflow.

BTW: You should always put code and HTML directly in your question. Also lok into CSS, this is the tool to get familiar with when you use JSoup for scraping.

Answer (score -1):

You can select first sibling of parent element of `a` tag with this code:

```
for(Element x:links){
    System.out.println(x.getElementsByTag("a").first().text());
    System.out.println(x.getElementsByTag("a").first().parent().siblingElements().first().text());
}
```